# Decreasing execution time of parallel red/blue computation

Tags: parallel-processing, execution-time

So the general problem I am trying to solve is the red/blue computation. The general idea is that you have an NxN board with spaces, red chips that move right one space, and blue chips that move down one space. At each step in this computation, all of the reds that don't have something in their way (meaning a red/blue chip) move to the right, if they're at the edge of the board they jump to the front. Then after the red move is finished, the blues do the same thing, but they move down. Now the NxN board is split up into TxT tiles, where T divides N, and the computation stops when the concentration of any red/blue chip reaches a threshold percentage C in any of these tiles.

So my first thought to a parallel solution to this was to split up the computation amongst the processors by rows and columns. So roughly, take N, divide it by number of processors, and they do those rows and columns. But this solution wasn't that efficient. Then I thought of splitting it up into blocks, where each processor gets a N/sqrt(P)xN/sqrt(P) block where P is the number of processors, and then have mutexes on the edges, this sped up the computation a lot. But I think I came up with a better solution that has to do with bitwise operations. I can divide the number of rows and columns by 32, so I only have to do roughly 1/32 of the work. But here lies the problem, here is an example of a 4x4 board where 0=space, 1 = red, 2 = blue

```
0202
0221
1122
1102
```

The way I would store occupied reds in rows is

```
[0000]
[0001]
[1100]
[1100]
```

and the way I would store occupied blues columns is

```
[0000]
[1100]
[0110]
[1011]
```

and then I would have a complementing row and column matrix that had the information of all occupied cells, example here is all occupied cells in rows

```
[0101]
[0111]
[1111]
[1101]
```

and then here is all occupied cells in columns,

```
[0011]
[1111]
[0110]
[1111]
```

using all of this information is enough to do all the work for each row and column in essentially constant time. So far this method doesn't really matter because for every move I do on a row in the board, I need to update each column where it stores which cells are occupied, and then I end up doing the same amount of work as if I didn't do any of these bitwise operations. Is there any way that I could store these differently or deal with them differently so I could keep the decreased runtime?

Answer (score 0):

A  couple of alternatives  to consider in for data storage are Morton Z  order curves. Z-Ordered curves  allows you process rows & columns in blocks. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve
But general look a the application of quadtrees  for this of 2D problem see: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~hjs/pubs/Samettfcgc88-ocr.pdf

Another approach is to do this on parallel hardware like a GPU by using OpenCL or CUDA.

Comment: I think I understand the general idea of a Z-order curve, but how would this improve my run-time? If I store rows and columns in two different arrays, and for each change to a row in one array I need to change every column in the other, then I don't see how it changes the fact that I still need to change N columns.

Comment: I'm challenging the assumption "So my first thought to a parallel solution to this was to split up the computation amongst the processors by rows and columns. "  With  Z-order curves you process the data  as Tiles"  A tile can be  say 8x8.